# Seem to be getting bogus mouse click events in VB6

Tags: vb6, mouse, mousemove

I'm trying to build a program that counts how long it's been since the mouse was last clicked (and performs some action after a given interval of inactivity). Unfortunately, the mouse click event seems to fire constantly. txtLastMouseMove continually updates to show the current time every second, and txtTimeSinceMouseMove never gets above 1, and is usually 0.

Timer1 is set to 100 ms. Setting it to a longer interval slows down the updates, but they still never count properly.

What am I missing here? Why does the left-click mouse event happen continuously?

```
' Detect mouse clicks.
Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "User32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer

Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

' Detect mouse clicks.
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()

    Dim Ret                          As Integer
    Static datLastMouseMove     As Date
    Dim datThisMouseMove         As Date

    if (datLastMouseMove=0) then datLastMouseMove=now()

    Ret = GetAsyncKeyState(1) 'vbKeyLButton = 1
    If Ret < 1 Then
        ' The left mouse button was clicked.
        datThisMouseMove = Now()
        txtLastMouseMove.Text = Format(datThisMouseMove, "hh:mm:ss")
        txtTimeSinceMouseMove = Format(datThisMouseMove - datLastMouseMove, "hh:mm:ss")
        If ((datThisMouseMove - datLastMouseMove) * 24 * 60 * 60 > CDbl(txtInterval)) Then
            MsgBox "Mouse has not moved in " & Format(datThisMouseMove - datLastMouseMove, "hh:mm:ss")
        End If
        datLastMouseMove = datThisMouseMove
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I'm stupid.

"If Ret < 1 Then" fires anytime the mouse button ISN'T clicked. It should read "If Ret Then".